# How to tell Webpack not to read (exclude) unreachable files by tree shaking?

Tags: webpack, tree-shaking

Seems like the tree shaking feature of Webpack helps to remove unused code from the bundle. However, Webpack does read these unreadable files. How do I tell Webpack not to read them?

Here is an example:

index.js

```
import { bar } from './bar';

bar();
```

bar/index.js

```
export { bar } from './bar';
export { foo } from './foo';
```

bar/foo.js

```
import fs from 'fs';

export function foo() {}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { sideEffects: false }
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    usedExports: true
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```

Running Webpack result in the following error:
`ERROR in ./src/bar/foo.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in "/temp/webpack-test/src/bar'`

I expect Webpack to not read the foo.js file because there is no route from the entry point to this file.

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected.

There is a route:

1. ./src/index.js:

```
import { bar } from './bar';
```

-> by default routing  to {folder}/index.js if bar is a directory

2. bar/index.js:

```
export { foo } from './foo';
```

---> export .. from .. syntax also imports the designated file:

3. bar/foo.js

```
import fs from 'fs';
```

You are getting

```
Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in "/temp/webpack-test/src/bar'
```

because `fs` isn't available in webpack default `target: web` configuration.
You can bypass it by:

```
node: {
   fs: "empty"
},
```

but some things may not work.

Comment: Thanks Raz. I'm not concerned about the error. It was only to demonstrate the fact that Webpack parsed the `src/bar/foo.js` file. Since `foo` was not exported into the main `src/index.js` file, I would expect this file to be ignored.

Comment: Tree shaking is an optimization so it works after modules are parsed an built. Interesting to hear the community thoughts on if webpack should/shouldn’t parse those files at all. Maybe in future versions it wont