# Webpack is still parsing unused/unreferenced/not-entrypoint files

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I have the minimal Typescript+Webpack setup from the doc, with the following files :

### Files

- src/

  - index.ts // only a console.log in here
  - unused.ts // only a console.log + type error in here

### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

### Problem

When I run a `webpack build`, it fails and show the type error in `unused.ts` even though it isn't an entrypoint nor in the descending import tree from one.

This is very problematic in my context as the real, huge, project is beneath a Perforce versionning server... which... leave the workspace in an unstable state when we switch streams (old files aren't cleaned and can contain no-more-revelant typings which fails the build)

=> **Do you know any way to tell webpack "only parse the import tree from entrypoints"?** (or any workaround to clean all unused files before build?)

#### Linked questions

[Same topic but is using exports/imports from/to the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63420678/how-to-tell-webpack-not-to-read-exclude-unreachable-files-by-tree-shaking)

Comment: "old files aren't cleaned when we switch streams" sounds like a problem with the way your workspace is set up, and is probably an easy fix.  I suggest posting a new question about that specifically, but I'm going to remove the perforce tag from this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found out : it turns out not to be a Webpack problem but a Ts-Loader problem, and it's **[already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289265/webpack-ts-loader-compiling-all-files-when-i-only-want-it-to-run-in-one-folder-f)**